# Implementation of memset to set a whole word instead of byte by byte in C

Tags: arrays, c, casting, byte, memset

So I'm trying to implement my personal `MemSet` that will do the same as `memset` but also:

- Copy word size chunks when possible, instead of byte by byte.
- Guarantee dest's alignment
- Test for all alignment possibilities

So this is my code:

```
void *MemSet(void *dest, int c, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char *runner = (unsigned char *)dest;
    
    size_t i = 0;
    
    unsigned char swap_word[sizeof(size_t)];
    
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(size_t); ++i)
    {
        swap_word[i] = (unsigned char)c;
    }
    
    if (NULL == dest)
    {
        return (NULL);
    }
    
    while (n > 0)
    {
        /* setting byte by byte */
        if (n < sizeof(size_t) || (((size_t)runner & (sizeof(size_t) - 1)) != 0))
        {
            *runner++ = (unsigned char)c;
            --n;
            printf("Byte written\n"); /* for debugging */
        }
        else
        {
            /* setting a whole word */
            *((void **)runner) = *((void **)swap_word);
            runner += sizeof(size_t);
            n -= sizeof(size_t);
            printf("Word written\n"); /* for debugging */
        }
    }
    return (dest);
}
```

What am I doing here?

- creating an unsigned char pointer `runner` to run over the `dest` but without changing it address so I'll be able to return it as a return value.
- creating a ready `swap_word` array, with the size of `sizeof(size_t)` because this size determines whether my machine is 32 or 64 bit (and therefore the `WORD` size is 4 or 8 bytes. This array will swapped when I'll need to set a word.
- running a simple `while loop` that will check if there are more than `sizeof(size_t)` bytes left to set , if not, it means for sure we won't be able to set a whole word and then set them byte by byte.
- Another option to set the bytes byte by byte is if the address isn't divides by 4 or 8 (again, depends on the machine), which means I won't be able to set up a word without crossing `WORD Boundary`, so just set them byte by byte until I'll reach an aligned address.
- Only option to set up a whole word is only if the data is already aligned to the `WORD size` of the machine, and then just set up 8 bytes (just set them up using the array of `swap_word` we made earlier, and advance 8 more addresses.
  I'll do it by using casting of

  *((void **)runner) = *((void **)swap_word);

and this is my test file:

```
int array[] = { 2, 3 };
    
int main () 
{
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Before MemSet, target is \"%d\"\n\n", array[i]);
    }
    if (NULL == MemSet(array, 3, 2 * sizeof(int)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"MemSet failed!\n");
        
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("After MemSet, target is \"%d\"\n\n", array[i]);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Output is:

```
Before Memset, target is "2"

Before Memset, target is "3"

Word written
After Memset, target is "50529027"

After Memset, target is "50529027"
```

Why aren't the elements are '3'? both of them?
I'm using here

```
MemSet(array, 3, 2 * sizeof(int))
```

Which, by theory, needs to set up both of the elements as `3` because the array uses `2*sizeof(int)` spaces in the memory, and I set up all of them as `3`.

What do you think?
And also, how can I check if my alignment works?

Thanks.

Comment: The overhead of your code is defeating all of the advantages it might be having over a simple byte-wise memset.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm just following the instructions of my task, I have to add this option of setting a whole word if that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function has multiple problems:

- you test for word size move at each iteration, which is likely slower than the simple byte operation.
- `*((void * *)runner) = *((void **)swap_word);` is incorrect because it violates the aliasing rule and because `swap_word` might not be correctly aligned for the `void *` type.

You should run separate loops:

- the first one to align the destination pointer
- the second one to set full words, possibly more than one at a time
- the last one to set the trailing bytes if any

Here is an example:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// assuming uintptr_t has no padding bits
void *MemSet(void *dest, int c, size_t n) {
    if (dest != NULL) {
        unsigned char *p = dest;
        if (n >= sizeof(uintptr_t)) {
            // align destination pointer
            // this test is not fully defined but works on all classic targets
            while ((uintptr_t)p & (sizeof(uintptr_t) - 1)) {
                *p++ = (unsigned char)c;
                n--;
            }
            // compute word value (generalized chux formula)
            uintptr_t w = UINTPTR_MAX / UCHAR_MAX * (unsigned char)c;
            // added a redundant (void *) cast to prevent compiler warning
            uintptr_t *pw = (uintptr_t *)(void *)p;
            // set 16 or 32 bytes at a time
            while (n >= 4 * sizeof(uintptr_t)) {
                pw[0] = w;
                pw[1] = w;
                pw[2] = w;
                pw[3] = w;
                pw += 4;
                n -= 4 * sizeof(uintptr_t);
            }
            // set the remaining 0 to 3 words
            while (n >= sizeof(uintptr_t)) {
                *pw++ = w;
                n -= sizeof(uintptr_t);
            }
            p = (unsigned char *)pw;
        }
        // set the trailing bytes
        while (n --> 0) {
            *p++ = (unsigned char)c;
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Note however that the above code is unlikely to beat `memset()` because:

- the compiler may expand the above logic inline for constant sizes, skipping the alignment tests if the destination pointer is known to be aligned or if the CPU allows unaligned access.
- the library may use specialized instructions such as SIMD or REP/STOS to increase throughput depending on the actual target CPU.

The reason for the surprising results is `int` spans 4 bytes, each of which gets set to `3`, so the resulting value for the integer is `0x03030303`, which is exactly `50529027`.

Comment: Candidate alternative to `(uintptr_t)0x0101010101010101` --> `UINTPTR_MAX/0xFF`.  Now not limited to `sizeof(uintptr_t) <= 8`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: thanks! I found an even more general formula, allowing for non 8-bit bytes... Only assuming no padding bits.

Comment: `while ((uintptr_t)p & (sizeof(uintptr_t) - 1))` is a reasonable, but not specified way to attain alignment.  No way to do it spec-wise in C.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I could use `while ((uintptr_t)p & (alignof(uintptr_t) - 1))` but it would be less portable.

Comment: I like the `4` idea, but maybe use a `#define CHUNK 4` or the like.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: good idea, but then I would need to rely on loop unrolling.

Comment: `(uintptr_t)p & anything` is assuming a math property of the converted pointer - pointer values are not specified as linear, yet most certainly are.  Nice work IAC.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use `uintptr_t` , that's why I'm using `size_t`

Comment: so I changed every place you wrote it to `size_t`. It compiles and runs but regarding `strings` being sent to the function - it does not work. Regarding int, it does work, for the example above sending an `int array` of 2 elements, it sets the number `24` for the first elements, but the 2nd one is `0`. Instead of them both being `3`

Comment: @NoobCoder: I added an explanation for the `50529027` value you observe. There must be another problem when copying the above code to get the result in the comment. Especially what do you mean by *regarding strings being sent to the function - it does not work*?

Comment: @NoobCoder: if you change all the `uintptr_t` to `size_t`, you must also change `UINTPTR_MAX` to `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @chqrlie ok it works, but it also worked before (thanks to your explanaion about the `int value` I now understand that my code also workes as needed). You made 3 loops that do the same as my one loop (in my opinion)

Comment: @NoobCoder: your loop performs 3 tests per word and has an alignment issue on `swap_word`, but it will work for current intel processors. My proposal reduces the number of tests for large sizes to about 0.25 per word and skips overhead for small sizes... It is more work but may be more efficient on average, depending on the application's specific use.

Comment: @chqrlie Last question - 
Can you explain me why `while ((uintptr_t)p & (sizeof(uintptr_t) - 1))` is valid and finds whether the address is aligned to 4 / 8 (based on the machine)? Why the `-1` is required here?

Comment: @NoobCoder: `sizeof(uintptr_t)-1` is a bitmask with all bits set below the alignment value. `while ((uintptr_t)p & mask)` is equivalent to `while (((uintptr_t)p & mask) != 0)` tests whether the pointer is unaligned, ie: has one of the low bits set.